# Finding out Task and Action in CLI Phalcon script

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm trying to create a debug utility that prints out the time a script took, the actual task name it used and actual action it ran

```
<?php
$di = new Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault\CLI();

$console = new \Phalcon\CLI\Console();
$console->setDI($di);
$console->handle($argv);

// something like this maybe???
$d = $console->getDI();
$d->get('dispatcher')->getTaskName();
?>
```

How do i get the task and action name (i don't want to grab it from argv)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dispatcher = $console->getDI()->getShared('dispatcher');
$task       = $dispatcher->getTaskName();
$action     = $dispatcher->getActionName();
```

should do the trick.